# How can I return groups of rows in Postgresql that have the same value in one column?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that will return rows grouped together by same first name, where last name is LIKE "some search string %"

For example, if I searched for last name `LIKE 'Smi%'` I want to get this result back

```
{
 [{1, tofu_spice, Joe, Smith}, {2, jsmith, Joe, Smithy}],
 [{3, smirthy11, Jack, Smirth}, {5, jackal, Jack, Smiles}],
}
```

| id | username | f_name | l_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tofu_spice | Joe | Smith |
| 2 | jsmith | Joe | Smithy |
| 3 | smirthy11 | Jack | Smirth |
| 5 | jackal | Jack | Smiles |
| 6 | kevs | Jack | Allie |
| 7 | rb2015 | Rob | Brown |
| 8 | luigi191 | Rob | Bran |

where the first array in my example result has all the rows with same first name "Joe" and second array has all rows with same first name "Jack".

Is it possible to return such a result? I know `GROUP BY` is used with aggregate functions, but I don't want to perform any such operations. I just want all the rows for each group returned. The query I've come up with so far (which I know is wrong) is  `SELECT * FROM users WHERE l_name LIKE "Smi%" GROUP BY f_name`

Comment: What is that result entry, an array of records?

Comment: If you want arrays, then yes you *do* want an aggregate function: `SELECT array_agg(*) FROM users WHERE l_name LIKE "Smi%" GROUP BY f_name`

Comment: @Bergi Yes that's what I was aiming for. I tried your example query but I can't get the `array_agg` function to work with the *. It seems to only work when I pass a single column (for example, `SELECT array_agg(username) FROM users WHERE l_name LIKE "Smi%" GROUP BY f_name`

Comment: Try `...array_agg(users.*)...`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that worked! Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to filter any resulting groups that only have 1 row in them? For example `SELECT array_agg(username) as grouped_users FROM users WHERE l_name LIKE "Smi%" AND grouped_users > 1 GROUP BY f_name`

Answer (score 2):

Manual reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

```
BEGIN;
CREATE temp TABLE users (
    id bigint,
    username text,
    f_name text,
    l_name text
);
INSERT INTO users
    VALUES (1, 'tofu_spice', 'Joe', 'Smith'),
    (2, 'jsmith', 'Joe', 'Smithy'),
    (3, 'smirthy11', 'Jack', 'Smirth'),
    (5, 'jackal', 'Jack', 'Smiles'),
    (6, 'kevs', 'Jack', 'Allie'),
    (7, 'rb2015', 'Rob', 'Brown'),
    (8, 'luigi191', 'Rob', 'Bran');
COMMIT;

SELECT
    array_agg(users.* ORDER BY id) AS grouped_user
FROM
    users
WHERE
    l_name LIKE 'Smi%'
GROUP BY
    f_name
HAVING
    cardinality(array_agg(users.* ORDER BY id)) > 1;
```

Comment: Why the `FILTER (WHERE id > 1)`?

Comment: @Bergi I misinterpreted the question. updated the answer. Hope the new is correct.

Comment: Ah, I see, you were trying to respect the comment asking "*if there is a way to filter any resulting groups that only have 1 row in them*". Using `HAVING` seems good, but I'd do it with a simple `COUNT(*) > 1` though :-)

Comment: @jian thank you! This works exactly how I need it to. I couldn't figure it out on my own.

Comment: @Bergi thank you as well. Where would you add the COUNT(*) > 1 though in jian's query? For example, I tried `SELECT array_agg(users.*) as grouped_user FROM users WHERE l_name LIKE 'Br%' and COUNT(grouped_user) > 1 GROUP BY f_name;`

Comment: @LePerMu In the `HAVING` clause, instead of the `cardinality(array_agg(users.* ORDER BY id)) > 1`